# GWT 2.5 native Drag and Drop in IE9 not working

Tags: gwt

I'm attempting to get Drag and Drop working in IE9 using the native GWT drag and drop events.  (Naturally, it works perfectly fine in all browsers except IE9)

I had a few issues which I ironed out working in Dev mode.  However, when outside dev mode it doesn't work.  So I put in this piece of code:

```
    Window.alert("supported DnD: "+com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.DragDropEventBase.isSupported());
```

It says "True" when running in dev mode, but "False" when not running in dev mode!?

Does anyone know why this is, if GWT 2.5 just does not support DnD in IE9?  Or if there is some way I can fix it.  It must be theoretically possible since it's working fine in dev mode.

Comment: Wild Guess - Check whether IE9 is running under some IE8 compatibility  mode?

Comment: Oh my word .... you are my hero SSR!!!  I feel like a complete fool.  I was indeed running in IE8 compatibility mode.  Great guess :)

Comment: Cheers!!! I posted a detailed answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ensure that you are running the sample code in the same browser and document mode in Hosted and Production mode. Also keep in mind GWT teams recommendation. https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideIE9

Ensure IE9 is not running under some IE8/IE7 compatibility mode.

For IE7 and IE8 the feature is disabled.
Reference:

- http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/detail?r=10138
- https://groups.google.com/d/topic/google-web-toolkit/0MkjaHsVfO4

GWT Team Test URL: http://gwt-cloudtasks.appspot.com

GWT Team Sample Code: http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/samples/mobilewebapp/src/main/java/com/google/gwt/sample/mobilewebapp/client/desktop/DesktopTaskEditView.java

Comment: I use IE 9 under Windows 7 (should be up to date... I apply the fixes regularly) and neither my application (with a standards doctype), a JS demo like http://jsfiddle.net/rvRhM/192/ nor the above test URL work there.

Comment: Try using http://gwt-cloudtasks.appspot.com demo d&d verify whether its any OS/Browser/Plugin issue . If the demo works then the issue would be with code.

Comment: That's what I meant by "above test URL"... It doesn't work on my IE 9.